# segmentation fault: 11 in C code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Why am I getting a segmentation fault with this code?

```
 /* solver.h header file */
 10 struct options{
 11     unsigned int one:1, two:1, three:1, four:1, five:1, six:1, seven:1, eight:1, nine:1;
 12 };
 13 
 14 
 15 /* structure to describe a cell */
 16 struct cell{
 17     short value;
 18     struct options open_options;
 19 };
```

solver.c:

```
  5 #include <stdio.h>
  6 #include "solver.h"
  7 
  8 
  9 
 10 
 11 
 12 int main(){
 13         struct cell board [9][9];
 14         int i=0,j=0;
 15 
 16 
 17         for(i = 1; i<10; i++)
 18                 for(j = 1; j<10; j++)
 19                         (board[i][j]).value = j;
 20 
 21         for(i = 1; i<10; i++){
 22                 for(j = 1; j<10; j++)
 23                         printf(" %d",(board[i][j]).value);
 24                 printf("\n");
 25         }
 26         return 0;
 27 }
```

output:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: You can start debugging the code yourself using `gdb`

Comment: The first element in a C array `x` is `x[0]`

Comment: Indeed `for(i=0; i < 9; i++){}` BTW: if you intend to implement a sudoku solver: bitmasks will be easyer, because you can mask all the numbers in one sweep.

Comment: @wildplasser yes, I am seeing that now.  I'm still pretty new to C; I was thinking that a bitfield could be masked similarly.  but thank you!

Comment: Bitmasks per cell are not as useful as bitmasks per row/column/box. And don't forget that you'll have to backtrack sometimes (after you have picked the low hanging fruit)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arrays are indexed from 0, so the loops should be `for(i = 0; i<9; i++)` and not `for(i = 1; i<10; i++)`

In your case, you probably override part of the stack, but in general, going out of boundaries results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`some_type array[9];` defines `array` to be an array of 9 elements, with subscripts going from 0 to 8 inclusive. You can't use `array[9]`.

Answer (score 1):

`board[9][9]` will contain elements with indices in the range 0...8, not 1...9. When you assigned to `board[9][whatever]`, you actually overwrote memory that didn't belong to you, and this happened to cause the program to explode when `return 0` handed control back to the C runtime and it started walking its structures to perform shut down.